# Difference between case class with parentheses and without

Tags: scala, case-class

I have a case class `case class FOO`. And would like to test a method `myMethod` that returns `FOO()` given parameter value `value1`.

I have a test like : `myMethod(value1) should equal FOO`.

The test failed with `FOO did not equal FOO()`.

What is the difference between `FOO` and `FOO()` ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A `case class Foo()` desugars into something equivalent to

```
class Foo() extends Product with Serializable {
  // some methods
}

object Foo extends (() => Foo) with Serializable {
  // some methods
}
```

So `Foo()` creates an instance of the Foo class while `Foo` is a reference to the Foo companion object.

However if your case class `Foo` has no parameters you should consider making it a *case object* instead. If you are not abusing your case class with internal mutable state[1] all `Foo()` instances should be indistinguishable anyway.

[1] If you are, consider using a regular class instead.